# How does mongodb compute network latency when using nearest?

Tags: mongodb

As to the mongodb doc, using nearest mode for read perference,
the driver reads from a member whose network latency falls within the acceptable latency window. However the doc does not tell what is the exact "network latency" is.

Does anyone know how is it evaluated? Using something like ping round trip time or the avg query time or through some specific query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know how is it evaluated? Using something like ping round trip time or the avg query time or through some specific query?

The following is applicable for MongoDB v3.2, v3.4 and current version v3.6. Based on [MongoDB Specifications: Server Selection](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-selection/server-selection.rst):

For every available server, clients (i.e. the driver) must track the average Round Trip Times (RTT) of server monitoring [isMaster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/isMaster/) commands. When there is no average RTT for a server, the average RTT must be set equal to the first RTT measurement (i.e. the first `isMaster` command after the server becomes available).

After the first measurement, average RTT must be computed using an exponentially-weighted moving average formula, with a weighting factor (alpha) of 0.2. If the prior average is denoted (`old_rtt`), then the new average (`new_rtt`) is computed from a new RTT measurement (`x`) using the following formula:

```
alpha = 0.2
new_rtt = alpha * x + (1 - alpha) * old_rtt
```

A weighting factor of 0.2 was chosen to put about 85% of the weight of the average RTT on the 9 most recent observations.

See also [Blog: Server Selection in Next Generation MongoDB Drivers](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/server-selection-next-generation-mongodb-drivers).

You may also be interested in [selecting servers within the latency window](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-selection/server-selection.rst) :

When choosing between several suitable servers, the latency window is the range of acceptable RTTs from the shortest RTT to the shortest RTT plus the local threshold. E.g. if the shortest RTT is `15ms` and the local threshold is `200ms`, then the latency window ranges from `15ms - 215ms`.

For example, in [MongoDB Python driver (PyMongo)](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/high_availability.html) by default the value of `localThresholdMS` is `15ms`, which means only members whose ping times are within `15ms-30ms` are used for queries.